# Menu not displaying submenus

Tags: jquery, css, menu, submenu

I can't figure out why this menu isn't working. The sub-menu or the ul li ul isn't displaying when I hover over the li yet when I resize to tablet/mobile width the menu works perfectly fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/cku6h/1/

```
<header id="site-header">
    <nav class="navbar cf inner">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Blog</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Link</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Why are you not using bootstrap is beyond me (they have [this exact functionality](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) pretty much pre-made for you)

Comment: @yuvi - Some would rather not bring in a huge set of assets to only get this functionality.

Comment: @cale_b [he doesn't have to bring the entire library](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)

Comment: @yuvi it is exactly that reason, theres too much in it and most importantly i dont want to use bootstrap. bootstrap isnt the answer to everything. Bootstrap if anything is the lazy mans way of creating a website there isnt no skill to it its just copy and pasting code.  its all done for you. and the menu is horrible to work with.

Comment: @Thomas'Renny'Renshaw I would call it "efficiency" more than "laziness." Why should anyone use **any** framework then? Why not just write your own framework for everything? (The answer is simple: don't re-invent the wheel!)

Comment: @Thomas'Renny'Renshaw like I've already mentioned, you can pick the exact parts of bootstrap that are relevant for you. You don't have to sign up for the whole package. It's not laziness, it's saving you time and money. Somebody already did what you're looking for, and he probably did it better. Why waste your time writing it all over again?

Comment: Unfortunately, we're not here to convince you to use a specific library, but instead help you with the issue at hand.

Comment: All sites that use bootstrap look the same. Bootstrap isnt the holy grail. it doesnt matter if i pick only the parts i need its still has very bad practice with it. if you use bootstrap youre a developer, not a designer.

edit: and yes youre right, i doubt ill be coming here again, i thought this site was full of helpful people that might be able to help me with my slight problem that ive spent an hour trying to figure out but for some reason i just cant get my head around it.

Comment: You're wrong about bootstrap.  It **is** a good solution, and your site can be themed to look very different.  *However*, I agree that this is not the place for this debate.  FYI, I prefer this css-only solution to a mobile navigation: https://coderwall.com/p/sujd_w

Comment: I'm not trying to antagonize you, I'm merely suggesting you use a pre made system and build over it. I'm speaking as both a designer and developed, and  am **currently** doing the exact same thing - taking bootstrap and writing my own theme to avoid a bland look. You can do whatever you want, and I'm sure someone will eventually take the time to help you with your problem (complex problems take longer to get help), this is just my suggestion. Furthermore, you can even use only the js files and add your own CSS to it. Whatever, just don't take this offensively, we're not against you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this to your css:

```
.navbar ul li:hover ul {
      display: block;   
}
```

in order to make it display the drop-downs on hover.

See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pak2W/

Comment: Thank you, cant believe it was something as simple as that. Thanks!

Comment: @Thomas'Renny'Renshaw if cale helped you, please consider marking his answer as correct

Comment: Sorry, first time here. Not aware of all the procedures